# SQL - update row based on previous row

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table that looks like the following.

```
ID            DateFrom         DateTo
33344        01-jan-2018     03-Jan-2018
33344        03-jan-2018     06-Jan-2018  
33344        09-jan-2018     NULL  
33344        10-jan-2018     NULL
```

This is how we receive the data so I don't have any control of it before it gets to this stage. Each ID will always have one row where the Dateto is NULL - we assume this is the latest date in the row. All other Datetos should be populated with the following rows DateFrom. Although for some ID's there will be only one row of data which should be a populated DateFrom and a NULL DateTo. For example, my desired output for the above would look like this

```
ID            DateFrom         DateTo
33344        01-jan-2018     03-Jan-2018
33344        03-jan-2018     06-Jan-2018  
33344        09-jan-2018     10-jan-2018  
33344        10-jan-2018     NULL
```

And if another 2 columns were added it would look like this

```
ID            DateFrom         DateTo
33344        01-jan-2018     03-Jan-2018
33344        03-jan-2018     06-Jan-2018  
33344        09-jan-2018     10-jan-2018  
33344        10-jan-2018     15-jan-2018
33344        15-jan-2018     27-jan-2018  
33344        27-jan-2018     NULL
```

I hope this makes sense and someone can help? I don't know where to start with this. Thanks, Jess

Comment: Do you want to update or select?

Answer (score 1):

You need `lead()`:

```
select t.*,
       lead(datefrom) over (partition by id order by datefrom)
from table t;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lead()`.  In an `update`, you can use an updatable CTE:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
             lead(datefrom) over (partition by id order by datefrom) as next_datefrom
      from t
     )
update toupdate
    set dateto = next_datefrom
    where next_datefrom <> dateto or (next_datefrom is null and dateto is null);
```